# java threads and memory mgmt - short vs long lived

Tags: java, multithreading, memory-management

Im chasing some memory issues in an app that pulls file names from a kafka queue and does some processing on each. This app runs in Docker with an instance / partition.

Each instance has a single consumer handle that retrieves the next file name and puts it into an **ArrayBlockingQueue**. Meanwhile there are several threads that take the next file from this queue and do the processing. Im using this secondary queuing as each file can take some time to copy and process (there are instances of "exponential backoff" used IE a thread may be sleeping) so it seemed prudent to have several 'in the pipeline' simultaneously.

My question is about the relative benefits (w/re memory mgmt) of doing it this way (several 'permanent' threads reading from a shared queue) vs launching a new thread for each file as it gets pulled from the queue. In this alternative track I would imagine a **FixedThreadPool** that would generate a new thread as each file was pulled from kafka.

Is there any advantage to one method vs the other?

---

### Edit:

my primary concern is minimizing GC time. I want to avoid having anything substantial sent to old-gen. This makes me think that the 2nd model is a better way to go.

Comment: you may want look into Executors and the ThreadPool implementations thereof

Comment: Generating a new thread for each file might make it difficult to impose a limit on the maximum number of threads, so you might run out of memory or take more CPU resources at once than acceptable.

Comment: @ammoQ with a FixedThreadPool I can control the # of active threads.

Comment: oh,I missed that part, sorry for the confusion

Comment: Using a FixedThreadPool is almost the exact opposite of "launching a new thread for each file."

Comment: @jameslarge my thinking was to exit each thread (and have the pool create a new one) after processing a file.

Comment: The entire point of using a thread pool is to _avoid_ creating threads when there's new work for the program to do.  The thread pool returned by `Executors.newFixedThreadPool()` is an extreme example of that:  It initially creates however many threads, and then it never destroys them or creates any more after that.